# Managing exceptions in sonarqube reports

Tags: code-coverage

One of our SonarQube quality gate (e.g. code Coverage or duplicate code lines) is failing and team wants to take an exception for the same. Is there a way in SonarQube on how we can manage and track this exception - maybe visualizer tag in SonarQube report that this rule is applicable in ideal scenario but right now  it is an exception.

checked various articles

Comment: Hi team,
Kindly update on this query.